# Any way to have CPU temperature in the menu bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-recommendation, menu-bar, cpu

I tried [SMC fan control](http://www.eidac.de) and [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) but it does not update the temperature and I do not wish to change the fan speed.

Comment: Could you expand on why SMCFanControl sucks? It's ben working well for me.

Comment: it doesnt update the temp. it stays at the same level. also, i dont want to change fan speed

Comment: Did you tried something like [iStat Menus 5](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)?

Comment: smcFanControl should update the temperatures live, whether you use it to adjust the fan speed or not.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is an old question, but by the end of 2020 there is a really nice open source utility — [iGlance](https://github.com/iglance/iGlance). Just tried it and it seems to work really fine. There are some minor issues with appearance under some circumstances, but otherwise it is very solid.

Answer (score 5):

[Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) was last updated in 2009. So maybe it is not compatible with your OS.

I recently abandoned the fantastic [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) (free) for [iStat Menus 5](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), since the later provides even more info on practically all Mac sensors. [Hardware Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/HardwareMonitor.html) and [System Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/SystemMonitor.html) are also capable of showing sensor information in the menu bar.

Answer (score 4):

iStatMenu will give you what you need. And a whole lot more besides - all in a nice tightly integrated package that sits in your menu bar.

Answer (score -3):

It is best achieved by installing CleanMyMac X and have it in the menu bar. It will update you with CPU temp., Memory, battery too

Comment: Nothing is "BEST" achieved with CleanMyMac.