# Free software that monitor CPU temperature under El Capitan?

Tags: macos, cpu

Is there some free software that can show CPU temperature in real time for OS X El Capitan?

[Any way to have CPU temperature in the menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169868/any-way-to-have-cpu-temperature-in-the-menu-bar) doesn't provide such an option.

Comment: There are several apps listed there, 2 of which I've used [smc & iStat]; both of which do what you're asking.

Comment: not free though

Comment: [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/) is.

Comment: Does smcFanControl supports El Capitan? I found it only says it supports Lion

Comment: smc has been reported to cause problems with El Capitan on some forums, just FYI @Tim

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody suggested it yet, you can try Macs Fan Control.
I'm using it for MBP on El Capitan 10.11.5, and it shows real temperature.
http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control

Answer (score 2):

smcFanControl has been good for me. It is simple but perfectly does the one thing I need: providing me the temperature.

https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl.git

If you have homebrew, you can use
`brew cask install smcfancontrol` to install the program.

However, as others noted, it may not perform perfectly so if that is the case for you, you can use https://www.derman.com/iMac-Fan-Control, which is also good.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option, and the one I use, is [iStat Menu](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

There are hundreds of different configurations and sensors you can use to monitor every aspect of your Mac.  See the image below for a small example.  This is not freeware but you can try it out for 14 days for free to see if it works for you.

[image]